# Tomcat repeated 401 and the client nonce cache

Tags: tomcat

I've got a Tomcat 6.0.35 service with a SOAP based webapp protected by Digest Authentication. We are seeing issues with various users getting repeated 401 responses since we upgraded to 6.0.35. Additionally we are getting the following entries in Catalina log:

```
WARNING: A valid entry has been removed from client nonce cache to make room for 
new entries. A replay attack is now possible. To prevent the possibility of 
replay attacks, reduce nonceValidity or increase cnonceCacheSize. Further 
warnings of this type will be suppressed for 5 minutes.
```

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Digest Authenticator Valve" for Tomcat 6.0.35 supported the following attribute:

> cnonceCacheSize -> To protect against replay attacks, the DIGEST
>   authenticator tracks client nonce and nonce count values. This
>   attribute controls the size of that cache. If not specified, the
>   default value of 1000 is used.

Tomcat 6.0.36 (released on Oct 19, 2012) contains the following changes regarding Digest Authentication (extracted from Tomcat [changelog](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/changelog.html)):

> Various improvements to the DIGEST authenticator including [52954](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52954), the
>   disabling caching of an authenticated user in the session by default,
>   tracking server rather than client nonces and better handling of stale
>   nonce values.

I'd suggest you give Tomcat 6.0.36 a try, since it includes varios improvements related to Digest authentication. Also take a look at the "Digest Authenticator Valve" [configuration options](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Digest_Authenticator_Valve).